# why the data does not add in database mysql?

Tags: php

I have to make one system where the system requires the process of adding new information. The process flow is the process of adding the new information carried by the employee where all the information, name and id of staff will insert in mysql database.  When I tried the process of that, I found `staff_id` and `staff_name` was empty in database mysql.

This is my addStaff.php

```
<?php
include("authenticationStaff.php");
include ("dbase.php");  

        $query= "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_name ='".$_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);


        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $id = $row["id"];
        $staff_id=$row["staff_id"];
        @mysql_free_result($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function Validate()
{
    if (document.addStaff.project_name.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Project Name!');
       document.addStaff.project_name.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.project_id.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Project ID !');
       document.addStaff.project_id.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.location.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Location!');
       document.addStaff.location.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.cost.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Cost!');
       document.addStaff.cost.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.pic.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Person In Charge!');
       document.addStaff..pic.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if (document.addStaff.detail.value == '') 
    {
       alert('Please Insert Detail about the Project!');
       document.addStaff.detail.focus();
       return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="869" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <td width="645" height="50" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Welcome ,&nbsp; You log in as &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];?> </strong></td>
      <td width="224" align="right" valign="middle"><strong><a href="logout.html" title="Logout">Log Out</a></strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <?php
   $idURL = $_GET['id'];
   $query ="SELECT *
    FROM staff s
    JOIN inter1 i
    ON (s.staff_name=i.staff_name)";

$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("Could not execute query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH); // using numeric index or array index

    $staff_id = $row['staff_id'];
    $project_name = $row['project_name'];
    $location = $row['location'];
    $detail = $row['detail'];
    $pic = $row['pic'];
    $staff_name = $row['staff_name'];
    $project_id = $row['project_id'];


    @mysql_free_result ($result);
?>
   <center>
  <form action="addStaff_process.php?id=<?php echo $staff_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="add_process" id="add_process" onSubmit="return Validate()" >
  <table border="1" width="70%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" >
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PROJECT NAME :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="project_name" cols="50" rows="2" id="project_name"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
     <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PROJECT ID:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="project_id" cols="50" rows="2" id="project_id"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >LOCATION :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="location" cols="50" rows="2" id="location"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="">
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" > COST :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="cost" cols="50" rows="2" id="cost"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="" >
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" >PERSON IN CHARGE :</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="pic" cols="50" rows="3" id="pic"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td   align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">DETAIL ABOUT THE PROJECT:</td>
      <td  align="left"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" ><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <input class="form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return Validate()"/>
          <input type = "reset" value = "RESET" />
        </p>
  </form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my addStaff_process.php

```
<?php
include("authenticationStaff.php");
include ("dbase.php");

    extract( $_POST );

    $idURL = $_GET['id'];
    $project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $cost= $_POST['cost'];
    $pic= $_POST['pic'];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'];
    $project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
    $staff_id = $_POST['staff_id'];
    $staff_name = $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];


$result ="INSERT INTO inter1 (project_name,location,cost,pic,detail,project_id)
 VALUES ('$project_name','$location','$cost','$pic','$detail','$project_id')";
$query = mysql_query ($result, $conn);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location='pageStaff.php'</script>";
}
  else{

$query1 = "UPDATE inter1 SET staff_name = '$staff_name',staff_id = '$staff_id' WHERE staff_name=$idURL";
$result1 = mysql_query ($query1, $conn);


if($result1){
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location='pageStaff.php'</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Can someone see where I am going wrong?if you need any more info then please let me know. thanks.

Comment: What does mysql_error() say?

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: error in line $staff_id = $_POST['staff_id']; :- undefined value..

Comment: missing quotes assuming this is a string `WHERE staff_name='$idUR'`

Comment: have you tried echoing value of staff_id ? maybe its empty

Comment: only this error I found because it does not show..

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: echoing value?? already try but still empty..

Comment: if you tried to echo $staff_id = $_POST['staff_id'];
    $staff_name = $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME']; then its empty, thats why it is also empty in the database

Comment: so @daR what should I do??

Comment: can you guys show me the correct coding??I really no idea to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `session_start();` at the start of every page that accesses the session values.

Comment: I already put session_start(); index page..

Comment: you need to put this in every page where you want to access the session values

Comment: are you sure because when I put this  in adStaff.php this error come up..Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\addStaff.php on line 14

Comment: oh then you might have written it in authenticationStaff page,becuase you are no where including index.php

Comment: have you try to print all post values and session values and checked whether all the values are present or not?

Comment: yup I put only in authenticationStaff..so what should I do to make data staff_id and staff_name insert in database??

Comment: as you have included that page now,no need to write sessionstart again, just try to check the values by printing first.

Comment: I already check and only value of staff_id and staff_name does not update in database...

Comment: no iam asking whether these variables are having empty values or non empty values?

Comment: and also `$_POST['staf_id']` you are passing it from anywhere,the staff id is already in `$idURL = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: oooo.. non empty value

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\addStaff_process.php on line 22..so how to fit it??

Comment: it means your query is not executed